How to Install Logstash onto EKS Cluster with Terraform
I have an existing EKS cluster that I deploy using terraform. I am looking at how to install Logstash onto this cluster by also using terraform. Is this possible? I am looking for guidance on how to achieve this.
I was looking at using the helm provider to do this but can't see any clear explanation on how to do so. This is my terraform script for my EKS cluster:
eks.tf
# Copyright (c) HashiCorp, Inc.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MPL-2.0

provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  profile = var.profile
  default_tags {
    tags = {

    }
  }
}

# Filter out local zones, which are not currently supported 
# with managed node groups
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  filter {
    name   = "opt-in-status"
    values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
  }
}

locals {
  cluster_name              = "test-eks-cluster"
  cluster_enabled_log_types = []
}



module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.15.3"

  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.27"

  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true
  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true

  vpc_id     = "vpc-00"
  subnet_ids = ["subnet-e", "subnet-9"]

  cluster_enabled_log_types = local.cluster_enabled_log_types

  create_cloudwatch_log_group = false

  tags = var.tags


  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    #ami_type = "ami-06d7aa002b2e3009b"
    ami_type = "AL2_x86_64"
    tags     = var.tags

    xvda = {
      device_name = "/dev/xvda"
      ebs = {
        delete_on_termination = true
      }
    }


  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    one = {
      name = "node-group-1"

      instance_types = ["t3.large"]

      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 3
      desired_size = 2
      tags         = var.tags
    }
  }
  # access_entries = {

  #}
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy"
}

module "irsa-ebs-csi" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-assumable-role-with-oidc"
  version = "4.7.0"

  create_role                   = true
  role_name                     = "AmazonEKSTFEBSCSIRole-${module.eks.cluster_name}"
  provider_url                  = module.eks.oidc_provider
  role_policy_arns              = [data.aws_iam_policy.ebs_csi_policy.arn]
  oidc_fully_qualified_subjects = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"]
  tags                          = var.tags
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs-csi" {
  cluster_name             = module.eks.cluster_name
  addon_name               = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  addon_version            = "v1.30.0-eksbuild.1"
  service_account_role_arn = module.irsa-ebs-csi.iam_role_arn
  configuration_values = jsonencode({
    controller = {
      extraVolumeTags = {
        

      }
    }
  })
}



Bitnami offers excellent Logstash helm chart here. You can learn about helm_release with example here.
